# How to update a variable after ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax

well, here my code
From my index.php:

```
<a href="#" id="save" class="save" onclick='UpdateStatus("<?PHP echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName();?>","<?php echo $_GET['id'] ;?>")'> save</a>
```

User can save one information when he clicks on this link.

Then, my fuction UpdateStatuts

```
function UpdateStatus(member1,id1) { // 
      /* VALUES */
        var member =  member1;
        var id =  id1;
        var statut = '1';
      /* DATASTRING */
        var dataString = 'member='+ member+'&id='+ id+'&statut='+ statut;

       console.log ("SOMETHING HAPPENS"); 

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
        url: "../../lib/tratement.php",
        data: dataString,
          success: function(){
          $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
           $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();

          console.log (dataString); 
          console.log ("AJAX DONE");
           }
      });
       return false;
    };
```

It works perfectly. But after users clicks on the first link, i want to display unsave instead save without reload the whole page.
In an another way, i want this

```
<a href="#" id="save" class="save" onclick='**RemoveStatus**("<?PHP echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName();?>","<?php echo $_GET['id'] ;?>")'> **Unsave**</a>
```

instead `<a href="#" id="save" class="save" onclick='UpdateStatus("<?PHP echo $fgmembersite->UserFullName();?>","<?php echo $_GET['id'] ;?>")'> save</a>`

Is it possible ?

Comment: if I've understand you have to add this in your ajax success function: `$('#save').html('unsave');`

Comment: Hi, i've added this line without result